# Testing axios post in nested redux dispatch

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, axios, moxios

I have an redux action someFunc that dispatches 4 actions including an axios post, this dispatch is called within another dispatch called someOtherFunc.

I am mocking the axios post with moxios and redux-mock-store to test the correct actions are dispatched.

I have successfully mocked and tested someFunc but when I try and test someOtherFunc moxios is not able to determine a post request is fired and instead I am getting a rejected post response i.e. rejected() is fired.

My questions is how can I get moxios to mock the nested post?

```
function someFunc() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(funcA());
        dispatch(funcB());
        dispatch(funcC());

        return axios.post(url, {}, config)
        .then((response) => {
            // on successful post request
            dispatch(success(response.data));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch(rejected(err));
        })
    }
}

function someOtherFunc(){
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch(someFunc());
        dispatch(operationComplete());
    }
}
```